# About Va yehi in bereshit

Tags: words, midrash, parashat-bereishit, creation

We learn from Chazal that whenever the Torah uses the word 'vayehi', it means something significant and awful is about to happen.

We find in Bereshit that when Hashem created the world and all things, He used the term 'vayehi' every day. If so, what tragedy took place at that moment, or what is awful message is there about the day?

Comment: Where did Chazal teach this?

Comment: @DoubleAA Megillah 10b-- but we come to the conclusion on the daf that 'VaYehi' does not signify something bad (only 'VaYehi BiYimei'). In fact, Bereishit Alef is used as a proof that 'VaYehi' is not necessarily bad.

Comment: @ephraimhelfgot Yes, that's the source Im familiar with. But that just made th OP's question even more confusing.

Comment: I'm posting this as an answer.

Comment: See page 241 of this pdf: http://www.bilvavi.net/files/%D7%91%D7%9C%D7%91%D7%91%D7%99.%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8.%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%9C.%D7%A9%D7%9D.%D7%98%D7%95%D7%91.pdf -- which quotes the Baal Shem Tov as teaching that "Vayehi Be;ashon Tzar" in this case refers to the Tzimtzum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Megillah 10b:

> אמר רב אשי כל ויהי איכא הכי ואיכא הכי ויהי בימי אינו אלא לשון צער
>
> R. Ashi replied: In all cases, vayehi sometimes has this signification and sometimes not, but “vayehi in the days of” always indicates trouble.

In fact, a few words earlier in the Gemara, the verse 'ויהי ערב ויהי בקר', 'Vayehi morning Vayehi evening', from Breishit 1, was used as a proof that 'Vayehi' does not necessarily signify a tragedy.

In sum, no tragedy happened on the six days of creation.

Comment: Thnks to efraim it wud be appreciate if u can elaborate more i dont mean your answer is not suficient juz i wanna know more toda raba